# Formatting of the date to the local "de_DE" fails

Tags: flutter, dart, date, format

I've gat a problem to format the Date of a DayView in the format of Germany. It ist always shown in yyyy-MM-dd, but the format I want tu use is dd.MM.yyyy. I tried a few things, but nothing works I want to.
At first I format the date like this

```
String datumDesTages = DateFormat.yMd('de_DE').format(DateTime.now());
```

this works fine, so date is shown as dd.MM.yyyy.
But for the DayTime I need a DateTime, so I try to parse it like shown below:

```
DateTime datumDesTagesDateTime =
        Intl.withLocale('de', () => DateFormat().parse(datumDesTages));
```

but then I get the error

```
The following FormatException was thrown building EventSet(dirty, state: _EventSetState#95b2d):
Trying to read .  from 12.2.2023 at position 4
```

the entire code is:

```
lass _EventSetState extends State<EventSet> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String datumDesTages = DateFormat.yMd('de_DE').format(DateTime.now());
    //String datumDesTagesString = datumDesTages.format(DateTime.now());
    DateTime datumDesTagesDateTime =
        Intl.withLocale('de', () => DateFormat().parse(datumDesTages));
    //DateFormat('d.M.y').parse(datumDesTagesString));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Termin setzen'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: DayView(
                  date: datumDesTagesDateTime,
                  style: DayViewStyle.fromDate(
                    date: datumDesTagesDateTime,
                    headerSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            // EventDetailScreen(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[50],
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(EventDetailScreen.routeName);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Thank you for your help.

kind regards
Patrick

Comment: This is the flutter_week_view package, right? If so, are you talking about the format of the date at the top of the screen?

Comment: The converter probably expects two digits for the day. That is 12.02.2023

Comment: @GrahamD yes, the format of the date at the top of the screen

Comment: There seems to be a DayBarStyle property for DayView that has itself a dateformatter property. I think you can probably use that to get your format. The DayView and DayViewStyle only take DateTime

Comment: @GrahamD thank you, that seems to be the correct solution, but unfortunately I don't know how to implement that in the right way. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the appropriate data for your language first.

Take a look at the readme from https://pub.dev/packages/intl

> Note that before doing any DateTime formatting for a particular locale, you must load the appropriate data by calling.
>
> ```
> import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
> ...
> initializeDateFormatting('de_DE', null).then(formatDates);
> ```

Comment: ok, I checked the readme. But what do I have to fill in at formatDates?